# laravel 4.2 and remember me update

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, remember-me

I add getRememberToken, setRememberToken, getRememberTokenName to User model, add "remember_token" column to user DB, run composer update.

Result: no errors, log in with remember me option goes same as it was before - "remember_token" in DB is still null.
+ i do not see `retrieveByToken()` and `updateRememberToken()` in `Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface`

What goes wrong?
I did or did not do something? Composer for some reason did not goes with "laravel/framework": "4.2.*" as it should? v4.2 did not have fix for remember me problem? `Auth::attempt()` should be modified somehow to generate and put data in remember_token? `Auth::logout()` not touching remember_token (i put random data and it still same after logout and login with or without remember me)
Where to dig?

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name','email','password','temp_password','code','status', 'remember_token'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
            return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
            return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
            return $this->email;
    }

    public function scopeCode($query, $code)
    {
            return $query->whereCode($code);
    }

    public function scopeEmail($query, $email)
    {
            return $query->whereEmail($email);
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }           
   }
```

Comment: Is your User model extending the Eloquent class directly? can you post your full User model code?

Comment: Added. And what about Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface without retrieveByToken() and updateRememberToken() after composer update? Why it is not there automatically?

Comment: Your model seems fine.
I haven't noticed this before, but Laravel 4.2 is not out yet you should change your composer.json to "laravel/framework": "4.1.*", and run "composer update"

Comment: yes, after deleting cookies in browser downgrade fix problem. Well, it seams i will not play with dev version anymore :) tnx

Answer (score 0):

Here's my `User` model for Laravel dev:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    protected $fillable = array('email', 'password');

}
```

A bunch of things to note here:

- Traits! Five of your methods should really be coming from [`UserTrait`](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Auth/UserTrait.html), and another from [`RemindableTrait`](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Auth/RemindableTrait.html).
- In `composer.json` you'll need to set `minimum-stability` to `dev` and then `php composer.phar update` (or, if you experience memory errors like I often do, `rm -rf vendor/ && php composer.phar install`). Note that `beta` won't currently work with the above user model, because `RemindableTrait` has actually been moved since the `BETA1` release; so I recommend the `dev` branch until the release of `4.2.0-BETA2`.
- Also note that currently there is a `4.2.0-BETA1` version of `laravel/framework`, but no `4.2.*` release of `laravel/laravel`. So if you try (like I did, for quite some time, in vain) to `create-project laravel/laravel --stability=beta`, you'll continue to get `4.1.*` as of right now, even though the 4.2 beta is out. It's all very confusing.

Finally, don't forget your user schema (stub at `php artisan auth:reminders-table`):

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('remember_token', 100)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

And your reminders controller (stub at `php artisan auth:reminders-controller`):

```php
<?php

class RemindersController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display the password reminder view.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getRemind()
    {
        return View::make('password.remind');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a POST request to remind a user of their password.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postRemind()
    {
        switch ($response = Password::remind(Input::only('email')))
        {
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

            case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
                return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($response));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getReset($token = null)
    {
        if (is_null($token)) App::abort(404);

        return View::make('password.reset')->with('token', $token);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a POST request to reset a user's password.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postReset()
    {
        $credentials = Input::only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );

        $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
        {
            $user->password = Hash::make($password);

            $user->save();
        });

        switch ($response)
        {
            case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
            case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check my answer at the end of this thread!

http://laravel.io/forum/04-21-2014-remember-token.

if you look at the Guard.php file the regenerating-token function is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel 4.2; I have an input with `name="rememberme"` on my login view with the following code in my controller:

```
if(Auth::attempt($logindata, Input::has('rememberme'))) 
{
    return Redirect::intended('/');
}
```

It works great; once I log in my session does not end until I explicitly log out.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4.2 Remember me steps:

1- your main user's table which used to check login must have rememberToken() in schema

```
Schema::create('Users',function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->bigInteger('organizer_id');
    $table->boolean('status');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();

});
```

2- View: checkbox for remember me, like i have

```
{{Form::label('remember','Remember Me')}}
```

3- Login Controller:

```
if (\Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password') ), (Input::get('remember')==1 ? true : false)))
{
   return Redirect::to('_admin/home')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
} else {
  return \Redirect::back()
    ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
    ->withInput();
}
```

`(Input::get('remember')==1 ? true : false)` this line of code should work for remember me